# Timer Circuit about 1 hour intervals

Tags: timer

I want to make a circuit that runs a small DC motor for about 30sec to 1min every one hour.
I guess that a 555 timer won't work.
any ideas ?

Comment: You should be able to do something like that with a CD4060.

Comment: That depends on your definition of an hour... how accurate does it need to be. If you need it accurately at one hour, use a cheap micro.

Comment: Others might suggest you use a small a cheap MCU.

Comment: It doesn't to accurate at all. a 5 min error or even alittle higher is ok.

Comment: Then a CD4060 may be your simplest best. https://www.google.ca/search?q=CD4060+hour+timer&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV3_Ou0prTAhVm44MKHcARAdcQ_AUIBigB&biw=1680&bih=995#tbm=isch&q=CD4060+1+hour+timer&imgrc=BJl0SIWTMi_GbM:&spf=387

Comment: You could use a 555 and a counter to get to one hour, but the accuracy would be abysmal. Best DIY solution; a small processor like the ATTiny85 and a relay .....cheapest effort/cost solution, search on Ebay for "Timing Delay Relay Module"

Comment: I'm just an armature but I think the on and off time in the CD4060 case is equal, I mean the motor will be off for an hour then ON for an hour. I just want it on for half or one MINUTE.

Comment: Then use the half hour CD4060 output to trigger a one-shot  555 to generate a 30 second pules that turns on the relay.

Comment: I'd use a 74HCT4060 and take a divide by 64 off the counter outputs using a 74HCT30 AND gate.

Comment: How many seconds per hour error must it be for cycle accuracy 10%? 1% 10 ppm?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're not asking how to drive a motor from logic.

This is an answer and also a personal design philosophy. I don't like discrete logic circuitry, it's inflexible and I believe outdated.  I prefer to use "soft" circuitry at every opportunity.  So I'd suggest something from the Arduino range, looking towards the smaller end.  So things like the Nano:-

[image: nano]

or

[image: trinket]

You can see that the latter (the Trinket) is not vastly larger than the 555 plus socket.  And consider the huge flexibility that gives you.  It can do any timer task you like from microseconds till the end of the Universe, all with equal accuracy (probably just a few % - perhaps less if it's crystal controlled).  And you can change the programming whenever you please, which you can't do with a hard wired dedicated timer circuit.

This can also do variable speed control (with no additional hardware) which is impossible with a fixed timer.  This may(not) be relevant to you.

Comment: Nice fingernails. For the best accuracy (as in real-time clock), the Nano may be worth avoiding as it's not got a crystal clock.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks, they take me ages to do.  It's the old  precision vs. accuracy adage.  As long as temperature effects aren't too bad, you can simply calibrate the Nano's delays against a better clock.  This is kinda the flexibility I was referring to. Anyway, you'd have to do the same but with a screwdriver & pot if you had a 555 + counter design.  Perhaps the OP doesn't mind some slack in his application?

Comment: Is that little silver device with 16.000 printed on it (just next to the Mega chip in my piccy) not a crystal then?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany ...of course the Nano has a crystal clock, but it won't be quite as accurate as a 32 KHz real time clock chip ....but I don't think the OP would find it inaccurate for the task (replacing a 555 timer). Even the Nano (ATMega328) or ATTiny85 RC clock will provide better accuracy than a 555 Timer, achieving about +/-1% when calibrated.

Comment: @pauluszak No, it's a ceramic resonator which is a couple of orders of magnitude less accurate than even a cheap crystal (0.5%. - ish) and thus only a bit better stability than a calibrated oscillator. One way to tell (sometimes) is that there are no external load capacitors.

Comment: *".. answer and also a personal design philosophy. I don't like discrete logic circuitry, it's inflexible and I believe outdated. I prefer to use "soft" circuitry at every opportunity."* As much as I agree with you, except perhaps the outdated part, it is also prudent to remember not everyone has the skills and capability to master coding a micro either. Especially on here. I tend to believe.. if they have to ask a question like this... they clearly don't have that skill set yet. That's why I usually just say, use a micro first then give them an old school alternative.

Comment: Continued : Good well written answer though.

Comment: @JackCreasey The device used is called a "ceramic resonator" and behaves like a rather horrible crystal with built-in capacitors. The Q is very low, which of course means it starts more quickly than a crystal oscillator but the stability is poor. [Here](http://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/timingdevice/ceralock/p16e.ashx) is a typical datasheet. Look at part number "CSTCE16M0V53-R0". If you are not familiar with these devices, they are useful in high volume product design. They are, for example, accurate enough for reliable serial communication w/o trim.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany. Sure I understand exactly what they are.....but they are by far more accurate (and stable) than could ever be achieved with a 555 timer circuit.....don't you agree??

Comment: @JackCreasey Sure, but a lot of time these once a day applications turn out to be even fussier than a normal crystal can handle, because the OP has not worked out what the consequences of inaccuracy are. I like the 280ppb oscillators for such applications (+/-1.5 minutes drift per 10 years). Gross overkill, perhaps, but not so expensive.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  By the way I think that what you see on the Arduino is a more like this: http://www.abracon.com/Resonators/abls.pdf  These are still categorized as "Resonators" but have a not unreasonable  accuracy of better than +/-150ppm and drift over temperature of better than +/-150ppm. Much better than the Murata resonators of which I've used many at 10 and 16 MHz in early AVR's.

Comment: @JackCreasey no, those are ordinary HC49U/S crystals typically 50ppm. Physically **much** bigger, and would require capacitors. The 0.5% (5000ppm) Murata part number I mentioned is directly off a Nano BOM, I am not guessing. They are maybe 10x more accurate than an untrimmed 555 but not that much more **stable** if good caps and resistors are used.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, you are certainly at the accurate end at 280ppb, I'm quite satisfied with my current favorite RTC the DS3231 at around +/2ppm